# Progressive number based on some SQL server columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I have the following table in SQL Server 2005 (without the GeoCodeNum column, which I want to calculate)

```
+-----------+---------+-------------+----------+------------+------------+
|   City    | Region  |   Street    |   Name   |  Surname   | GeoCodeNum |
+-----------+---------+-------------+----------+------------+------------+
| Sydney    | NSW     | Wall street | Chris    | Red        |          1 |
| Sydney    | NSW     | Wall street | Marc     | White      |          2 |
| Sydney    | NSW     | Sea street  | Joseph   | Orange     |          1 |
| Melbourne | VIC     | Ocean orad  | Jess     | Brown      |          1 |
| Florence  | Tuscany | Wine street | Luca     | Rossi      |          1 |
| Florence  | Tuscany | Wine street | Mario    | Verdi      |          2 |
| Florence  | Tuscany | Wine street | Luigi    | Carli      |          3 |
| Florence  | Tuscany | Beer street | Elena    | Sarzetto   |          1 |
| Venice    | Veneto  | Old street  | Giovanni | Casagrande |          1 |
| Venice    | Veneto  | New street  | Giuseppe | Giusti     |          1 |
+-----------+---------+-------------+----------+------------+------------+
```

I want to generate a GeoCodeNum based on the following rule:
*"assig a progressive number to records with the same set of City, Region and Street and".* It doesn't matter the order of the progressive number.

In the example Luca Rossi, Mario Verdi and Luigi Carli both live in Wine Street, Florence, so they have 3 differnts GeoCode numbers.
Giovanni Casagande and Giuseppe Giusti both live in Venice but in different streets so they have the same GeoCode number.

**How can i automatically generate the GeoCodeNum?**

I need to generate the results once time per year but I have almost 100000 records.

I don't know how to start, I've tried with MS Excel but it wasn't helpful.

Comment: Is the intention to store this new value in the database, or simply to use it for display purposes? The question is tagged as `sql` but you state that your initial attempt was with `MS Excel`, which is very different.

Comment: This would be a lot easier in 2008+ - no access to that?

Comment: @Peter Abolins just display the values in the query results. I dind't get any useful results with SQL so I tried export the results in Excel and use some functions, this is the reason I didn't insert the Excel tag.

Comment: @ChrisV unfortunatelly I can't use 2008+ version. I am using an old software which only works on SQL server 2005.

Comment: Rank() window function will work for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select *,
       row_number() over(partition by City, Region, Street order by Name, Surname) as GeoCodeNum
from yourTable;
```

Row_number() was appeared firstly in SQL Server 2005:
[Row_Number() function in SQL Server 2005](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3572301/RowNumber-function-in-SQL-Server-2005.htm)

Comment: @Rokuto Really? could you post a proof link, please? I was using it for 2 years before migrating to 2008 R2

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I've looked at [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql) but I forgot that `ROW_NUMBER` was introduced in 2005. One more time, sorry.

Comment: It works perfectly thank you very much @sepupic . It was exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: @Rokuto, you are lucky to be on 2016, I remember your yesterday comment on DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS :) and I still have 2008 R2

Comment: @sepupic Well, I've worked on 2016 only for few days (and only because we wanted to generate massive JSON). :) Now I'm working on 2008 R2 like you, and sometimes on 2014.

Answer (score 0):

I think this result your expecting

```
;With cte(City ,Region, Street,Name ,Surname  )
AS
(
SELECT  'Sydney'    , 'NSW'     , 'Wall street' , 'Chris'    , 'Red'       UNION ALL
SELECT  'Sydney'    , 'NSW'     , 'Wall street' , 'Marc'     , 'White'     UNION ALL
SELECT  'Sydney'    , 'NSW'     , 'Sea street'  , 'Joseph'   , 'Orange'    UNION ALL
SELECT  'Melbourne' , 'VIC'     , 'Ocean orad'  , 'Jess'     , 'Brown'     UNION ALL
SELECT  'Florence'  , 'Tuscany' , 'Wine street' , 'Luca'     , 'Rossi'     UNION ALL
SELECT  'Florence'  , 'Tuscany' , 'Wine street' , 'Mario'    , 'Verdi'     UNION ALL
SELECT  'Florence'  , 'Tuscany' , 'Wine street' , 'Luigi'    , 'Carli'     UNION ALL
SELECT  'Florence'  , 'Tuscany' , 'Beer street' , 'Elena'    , 'Sarzetto'  UNION ALL
SELECT  'Venice'    , 'Veneto'  , 'Old street'  , 'Giovanni' , 'Casagrande'UNION ALL
SELECT  'Venice'    , 'Veneto'  , 'New street'  , 'Giuseppe' , 'Giusti'   
)
SELECT
  City,
  Region,
  Street,
  Name,
  Surname,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY City, Region, Street ORDER BY Street) AS GeoCodeNum
FROM cte
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT city, 
       region, 
       street, 
       NAME, 
       surname, 
       Row_number() 
         OVER ( 
           partition BY city, region, street 
           ORDER BY NAME ASC) AS GeoCodeNum 
FROM   customeraddress;
```

Comment: Not just posting an answer, you could add little explanation which understand the solution better to OP and future readers as well.